# ggplot facet_grid with different y mapping

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Is it possible to use facet_grid with lines (or columns) of the grid mapping different data?

I have the dataframe:

```
data=data.frame(x = c(6, 10, 4, 6, 4, 4, 9, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 7, 8, 3), z1 = c(6, 6, 9, 8, 8, 2, 3, 1, 9, 8, 3, 9, 8, 1, 10, 7), z2 = c(8, 5, 6, 3, 9, 9, 8, 5, 1, 3, 5, 8, 8, 2, 3, 3), r = c('1L', '1L', '1L', '1L','1L', '1L', '1L', '1L', '2L', '2L', '2L', '2L', '2L', '2L', '2L', '2L'))
.
```

and currently I can combine 2 facet wraps for each y mapping I want:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=z1))+facet_wrap(~r)+geom_point(aes(colour=r))
p2 <- ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=z2))+facet_wrap(~r)+geom_point(aes(colour=r))
arrangeGrob(p1,p2,nrow=2)
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Is is possible to combine those in a single `facet_grid` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all your data in one plot, it's better to just reshape your data. Here i've used the `reshape2` library to make it easier

```
library(reshape2)
mm <- melt(data, id.vars=c("x","r"))
ggplot(mm,aes(x=x,y=value))+facet_grid(variable~r)+geom_point(aes(colour=r))
```